# Table Valued Parameter not found in the schema defined

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I've defined the following table valued parameter in my DB:

```
CREATE TYPE RVUSER.GXS_OTABTYP AS TABLE (
app_name VARCHAR(2000),
func VARCHAR(2000),
DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR(4000),
OWNER VARCHAR(30),
VERSION VARCHAR(30),
ISACTIVE VARCHAR(1),
FILENAME VARCHAR(4000),
FUNC_DESC  VARCHAR(4000),
READ_USERIDS VARCHAR(4000),
ADMIN_USERIDS VARCHAR(4000),
ISGLOBAL  VARCHAR(1),
LAST_UPDATEDBY VARCHAR(30),
ISAPPACTIVE VARCHAR(1)
)
```

While trying to invoke a Stored Procedure from `JAVA` which takes in the above `TVP` as a parameter kept giving me the error that: Unable to find `RVUSER.GXS_OTABTYP`.

```
cs = (SQLServerCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("exec RVUSER.saveGxAppRec ?");
        cs.setStructured(1,"RVUSER.GXS_OTABTYP",sourceDataTable);
```

Digging deeper, I tried to find out all the objects inside the schema `RVUSER` using:

```
SELECT name AS function_name   
  ,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name  
  ,type_desc  
  ,create_date  
  ,modify_date,*  
FROM sys.objects  
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) LIKE '%RVUSER%';
```

I wasn't able to find out the `TVP RVUSER.OTABTYP` that I defined.

So I checked in the 'sys' Schema and I could see a `TABLE_TYP` object named:`TT_GXS_OTABTYP_160F4887`.

I am unable to figure why the `TVP` is getting created in the sys schema, that too with a different name and not in the `RVUSER` schema that I've defined.

Need help to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure, that your `CREATE` statement had the rigth database as target?

Comment: Yes. Initially I thought that was the problem and re-ran the create statement again and got this warning: The type 'RVUSER.GXS_OTABTYP' already exists, or you do not have permission to create it. So It's not the wrong DB.

Comment: What happens if you fully qualify your types name (add server and db-name)?

Comment: I ran it on TOAD using the correct server and db-name.

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Hope someone enlighted comes by...

Comment: I tried using the schema 'dbo' as well. Even that creates the type in sys schema with a different name.

Comment: This does not solve your problem, but - as a workaround - you might use XML instead of a created type... This is easier in *cross-border-projects* ...